# Time for a Calculus Tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

We have several questions involving aspects of calculus:

- [Numerical Integration through Plotting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2072/44713)
- [Symbolic Integration of Polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66714/44713)
- [Evaluate CDF of Student-t distribution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/41333/44713)
- [Do the Chain Rule](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68126/44713)
- [Gamma Function Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63887/44713)
- [Symbolic Differentiation of Polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54162/44713)
- [Build the blancmange function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12479/44713)
- [Help me with differential calculus!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31930/44713)
- [Determine stability of a system using the Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11847/44713)

We already have tags for [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), [probability-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-theory), and various other sects of mathematics. I doubt that we won't have more calculus questions, so let's make a tag for the future.

Comment: You have the "create new tags" privilege for a reason.

Comment: @Doorknob Yeah, but I wanted to make sure on meta that it was approved first.

Answer (score 4):

The tag [calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) has been created. The 9 challenges linked in the question have been retagged to add this.

At least for starters, I've added the following information to the tag wiki.

Description:

> Use this tag for challenges involving integration or differentiation of functions.

Wiki:

> [Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus), not to be confused with [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), is the mathematical study of change. The main branches are differential calculus, which involves taking derivatives of functions, and integral calculus, which involves integrating functions.
>
> This tag should be used for any challenge which requires numerically or symbolically differentiating or integrating functions.

We should be vigilant in making sure that challenge authors do not confuse [calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) with [lambda-calculus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lambda-calculus), as they are entirely separate.

Comment: \o/ +1 Because Calculus.